# Resultados duplicados al seleccionar el cuadro combobox

Tags: jquery

Tengo un sistema donde es posible agregar nuevos colores (Incluir novas cores). Mira:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la opción Cuadrículas (Grades), podemos elegir Mujer y Hombre. Esta opción proviene de la base de datos y trae los tamaños para esa cuadrícula. En los tamaños de tabla tenemos una clave foránea de las cuadrículas de la tabla.

Sin embargo, cuando hago clic en la opción Agregar nuevo color (Incluir nova cor) y selecciono otra cuadrícula (Grades), los tamaños de esa cuadrícula también aparecerán en la primera cuadrícula seleccionada previamente. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que los tamaños aparezcan correctamente dentro de cada cuadrícula?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es el siguiente:

**HMTL**

```
<table width="100%" >
<tr class="linhas">
<td>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #367FA9; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold">Código de cores</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #367FA9; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold">Cor Básica</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #367FA9; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold">Grades</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center; width: 40%"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Referência"></td>
    <td style="text-align: center; width: 30%">
    <select name="CoresBasicas" class="form-control">
    <?php echo $metodos->comboCores($key); ?>
    </select>       
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: left;">
        <select name="Grades" class="form-control grades" style="width: 100%">
        <?php echo $metodos->comboGrades(); ?>
        </select>   
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3">    
    <?php //echo $metodos->listarTamanhos($grades); ?>
    <div class="mostrarGrades"></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="text-left">

<label for='files' class="upload">Selecionar fotos <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
<input id='files' type='file' name="Fotos[]" multiple>

</td>
</table>

</td>
<td  style="padding: 5px"><button type="button" class="removerCampo btn btn-danger" title="Remover linha"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remover</button></td>
</tr>              
<tr><td colspan="3" class="text-right">
<button type="button" class="adicionarCampo btn btn-success" title="Adicionar item"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Incluir nova cor</button>
</div>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function () {
  function removeCampo() {
    $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
    $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
       if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
       }
    });
  }

  $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
    novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
    novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
    novoCampo.find('select').val("");
    novoCampo.find('.mostrarGrades').empty();
    valorEscolhido = $(this).find('option:selected').val();   //PERMANECE
    novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
    removeCampo();
  });
});
$(document).ready( function ()
{
$(document).on('change', '.grades', function(){
    valorEscolhido = $(this).find('option:selected').val();  
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '<?php echo $caminhoAbsoluto; ?>/listar.php?v='+valorEscolhido,
        success: function(dados){
            for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){
                $('.mostrarGrades').html(dados[i]);             
            }
        }
    }); 
  });
});
```

**listar.php**

```
$grades = $_REQUEST["v"];
echo $metodos->listarTamanhos($grades);
```

**Método listarTamanhos($grades)**

```
 public function listarTamanhos($grades)
    {
        $visualizar = '<table class="table table-bordered">
                            <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #367FA9; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold">Tamanho</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #367FA9; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold">Quantidade</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #367FA9; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold">EAN</td>
                            </tr>';
        $sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM loja_tamanho_grades WHERE IdGrades = '".$grades."';");
        //while($isfast = mysqli_fetch_object($sql))
        while($isfast = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
            $sqlTamanhos = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM loja_tamanhos WHERE IdTamanhos = '".$isfast["IdTamanhos"]."';");
            $isfastTamanhos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlTamanhos);
            $visualizar .= '<tr>
                                 <td style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-size: 20px; font-style:Arial">'.$isfastTamanhos["Tamanhos"].'</td>
                                 <td><input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" value="0"></td>
                                 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="17" style="width: 100%"></td>
                               </tr>';        
            $visualizar .= '<tr>';
            $visualizar .= '</tr>';                                                
        }   
     $visualiza[] = $visualizar;
     return json_encode($visualiza);
    }
```

Perdón por mi español, pero espero que mi pregunta sea clara.

Comment: Como solucion rapida, se me ocurre que puedes modificar la query, para poder obtener registros unicos.

Comment: Hola Srsole Creo que el problema está en Jquery, porque en la consulta estoy usando la cláusula Where.

Comment: para estar seguros de lo que dices haz lo siguiente: var_dump($sql); (PHP) y ejecutalo directamente en tu gestor SQL. Si te devuelve resultados duplicados ya sabemos que es

Comment: no logro entender podrias ser un poco mas claro si tanto hombre mujer y cor solo se descuadra aqui o no se coloca como debe. nota porque traes codigo html atravez de ajax, esto aumenta mas el tiempo de respuesta de las consultas!

Comment: Cuando doy un `console.log (valorEscolhido)` en jquery, muestra correctamente cada valor elegido, pero cuando doy var_dump ($sql) en php, muestra el mismo valor. Por eso se está duplicando. ¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Comment: Hola byrro Lo siento, mi español no es bueno. No sé mucho jquery.

Comment: Creo que al agregar un nuevo color, debe tomar el valor e incluirlo solo en la nueva línea. ¿Pero cómo puedo hacer eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu código javascript tienes lo siguiente:

```
success: function(dados){
  for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){
    $('.mostrarGrades').html(dados[i]);             
  }
}
```

donde `$('.mostrarGrades')` se refiere a todos los elementos con `class="mostrarGrades"`, pero tú sólo quieres cambiar el que pertenece al mismo `TR` que el `SELECT.grades` que ha cambiado el usuario, por lo que tienes que restringir la búsqueda a dicha fila:

```
$(document).on('change', '.grades', function() {
  var sel = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/pruebas/fox11.php?v=' + sel.find('option:selected').val(),
    success: function(dados) {
      for(var i = 0; dados.length > i; i++) {
        sel.closest('TR').next().find('.mostrarGrades').html(dados[i]);          
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hola juanrpozo Intenté usar su código, pero los tamaños no aparecen.

Comment: Disculpa, era un error mío. Dentro del *success handler* de `$.ajax`, `this` se refiere al objeto `jqXHR`, no al `SELECT` ligado al evento `change`. Ya he corregido el código, verás que hago una referencia explítica al `SELECT` con la variable `sel`. Además el `DIV.mostrarGrades` que hay que cambiar está en el `TR` siguiente al que contiene el `SELECT`.

Comment: Perfecto, funcionó! ¡Muchas gracias! Saludos desde Brasil.